# Disable hardware back button while loadingctrl spinner is up?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there a way to disable an android hardware button (Motorola TC70 Android 5.1) while the loading controller spinner is up in an Ionic4 app?

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to do that????

back button means cancel current operation, you cant force your user to wait for your app

simply cant